# Facebook FQL friendslist_member is empty using Graph API v2.0

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm using Graph API Explorer with all of the permissions of my personal FB account. When I execute FQL request:

`SELECT flid FROM friendlist WHERE owner = me()`

I get the list of flids. But if I execute:

`SELECT uid FROM friendlist_member WHERE flid IN (SELECT flid FROM friendlist WHERE owner = me())`

I get an empty result, why?

Comment: Are you using API version 1.0 or 2.0? there's no way to retrieve friend list members in v2.0

Comment: You are correct! Because of API v2.0, friendlist_member table has more privacy restrictions. Resolved.

Comment: Added an answer and updated the tag and title to clarify which API version this was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Graph API v2.0 or later, this is expected - the names/IDs of a user's friendlists are retrievable (For example, to use in a privacy selector) but the list of friends inside the lists is not retrievable

This is mentioned in the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

Answer (score 0):

Change the API version to 1.0 then you can query friend list successful.

```
/v1.0/me?fields=friends
```